# Override Django MEDIA_ROOT with factory-boy

Tags: python, django, pytest, factory-boy

I'm testing a Django website using pytest and factory-boy. When I test a model with a FileField or ImageField I decorate the test method to override the MEDIA_ROOT setting with a temporary directory so any files created in the test are cleaned up.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=tempfile.mkdtemp())
def test_foo():
    models.ModelWithFile.objects.create()
```

When I create a model object with factory-boy that uses a FileField the decorator is ignored and a file is created in the original MEDIA_ROOT.

```
@pytest_factoryboy.register
class RefundImageFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.RefundImage

    refund = factory.SubFactory(RefundFactory)
    product_refund = None
    image = factory.django.ImageField(width=1000, height=1000)
    thumbnail = factory.django.ImageField(width=200, height=200)


@pytest.mark.django_db
@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=tempfile.mkdtemp())
def test_foo(refund_image_factory):
    refund_image_factory.create()
```

Is there some way I can get factory-boy to use the overrided MEDIA_ROOT? Alternatively is there some way I can get factory-boy to simply always use a temporary directory?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the factory? As far as I can tell, there is no reference to `MEDIA_ROOT` in factory_boy's source code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Xelnor. I've added the factory definition to my question. I don't think that factory-boy is doing anything with the MEDIA_ROOT, I assume the issue is with the path for the files being set in the class so it is not overridden by the decorator at run-time.

Comment: Indeed; maybe try to decompose the factory code by hand, e.g: `stub = RefundImageFactory.stub(); models.RefundImage.objects.create(refund=stub.refund, product_refund=None, image=stub.image, thumbnail=stub.thumbnail)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't  seem to be possible to create stubs with a FileField. I had assumed that what I was trying to do was a common pattern but it seems like it may not be possible without a drastic work around.

Comment: @axevalley Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: @exp1orer Unfortunately I don't think I did